# Is NSFetchedResultsController also caching the record set itself, or just some meta data about table display stuff?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I fear my english is too bad for the documentation ;) it feels like they try to say, a NSFetchedResultsController also caches the record set itself, hence it may query some lame web source for half an hour and then the next time display that data super fast from the cache? Or does it just cache some data about "how to display the stuff"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSFetchedResultsController fetches data from your Core Data store. It does not fetch data from other sources such as the web. You can fetch data from the web and insert it into your managed object context which can then be fetched.

As part of Core Data, NSFetchedResultsController benefits from optimizations including caching of managed objects (record data) for performance.